# Shape key looks different in between edit mode and object mode

Tags: modifiers, rigging, shape-keys

I want to know the cause of this problem and stop this happen.

I applied shape key to object from armature modifier with corrective shape keys.
When I enable the applied shape key in object mode, the gums of the model comes out of face mesh!

I tried fixing this in edit mode. By Selecting the gum mesh and Blending from basis it solved for the shape keys of eyes. I just need to disable the deform of the gum. But I need to tackle this odd shape key problem for the deformation of the mouth.

I can settle this problem by editing the shape manually but I want to know the cause of this problem.
Do you have any ideo of stop this problem to cause.

1. Why it looks different in edit mode and object mode?
2. Why saved shape key looks different from the original rigged deformation?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note, Disabling "Armature modifier/ bind to / vertex group" solved this glitch.